# Populate ParameterCollection w/ sp_columns (or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns) Results

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, data-binding, parameters

I'd like to build a ParameterCollection object based on the results of either `execute sp_columns MyTableName` or `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName'`.

The problem I'm having is assigning the appropriate data type to each Parameter ... I'm unsure of how to gather that information from either of the above two queries and convert it into a `System.Data.DbType` or `System.TypeCode`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Links: [MSDN: sp_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx), [MSDN: Information Schema.Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)

**Edit:** I guess what I'm looking for is functionality similar to `Type.GetType("TypeName")` that would accept a SQL data type.  For example, `DbType.GetType("int")` or `DbType.GetType("varchar")`.

**Edit:** Links from Answer: [MSDN: Enum.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually really easy to do :-) SqlDbType is an enum, and there's a nice static function on the Enum class which accomplishes just what your looking for:

```
 private  SqlDbType ConvertType(string typeName)
 {
      return (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), typeName, true);
 }
```

With this, you should have no trouble converting the output from your INFORMATION_SCHEMA query into a collection of SqlParameters.